# Elixir reflection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, python-elixir

I define some Entities which works fine; for meta programming issues. I now need to reflect the field properties defined in the model.

For example:

```
class Foo(Entity):
      bar = OneToMany('Bar')
      baz = ManyToMany('Baz')
```

Which type of relation is set: "ManyToMany", "OneToMany" or even a plain "Field", and the relation target?

Is there any simple way to reflect the Elixir Entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do introspection in Elixir as you would anywhere in Python -- get all names of attributes of `class Foo` with `dir(Foo)`, extract an attribute given its name with `getattr(Foo, thename)`, check the type of the attribute with `type(theattr)` or `isinstance`, etc.  The string `'Bar'` that you pass as the attribute to the constructor of any `Relationship` subclass (including `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany`) ends up as the `r.of_kind` attribute of the resulting instance r of the Relationship subclass.

Module `inspect` in the Python standard library may be a friendlier way to do introspection, but dir / getattr / isinstance &c are perfectly acceptable in many cases.